# How to count distinct values based on condition in sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

My table called matchEvent looks like this:

```
 eventId    playerId  matchId   eventName description
 --------------------------------------------------------
 100        50        1         goal      freeKick
 100        50        1         goal      shot
 200        50        2         foul      penalty
 300        51        3         goal      header
 300        51        3         goal      ownGoal
 400        51        4         goal      ownGoal
 400        51        4         goal      shot
```

I want to count all regular goals (but not own goals) scored by a specific player in a specific match.
I tried:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(my_db)
regular_goals = con.execute("SELECT playerId, matchId, COUNT(DISTINCT eventId) FROM matchEvent WHERE eventName = 'goal' GROUP BY playerId, matchId HAVING description <> 'ownGoal'").fetchall()
```

The problem is that HAVING clause seems to be filtering the groups based on group's top row value so it's giving me:

```
[(50, 1, 1),(51, 3, 1)]
```

while the result I expect is:

```
[(50, 1, 1)]
```

since my table contains only one regular goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT playerId, matchId, SUM(counter) total_goals
FROM (
  SELECT playerId, matchId, COUNT(DISTINCT eventId) counter
  FROM matchEvent  
  GROUP BY eventId, playerId, matchId 
  HAVING SUM(eventName = 'goal') > 0 AND SUM(description = 'ownGoal') = 0
) t
GROUP BY playerId, matchId
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nQK1uZrXZ1Hz6JcWQNDySF/5).

Or:

```
SELECT playerId, matchId, COUNT(*) total_goals
FROM (
  SELECT playerId, matchId
  FROM matchEvent  
  GROUP BY eventId, playerId, matchId 
  HAVING SUM(eventName = 'goal') > 0 AND SUM(description = 'ownGoal') = 0
) t
GROUP BY playerId, matchId
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nQK1uZrXZ1Hz6JcWQNDySF/7).

Or:

```
SELECT playerId, matchId, COUNT(DISTINCT eventId) total_goals
FROM matchEvent  
WHERE eventName = 'goal' 
  AND eventId NOT IN (SELECT eventId FROM matchEvent WHERE description = 'ownGoal')
GROUP BY playerId, matchId
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nQK1uZrXZ1Hz6JcWQNDySF/9).

Results:

```
| playerId | matchId | counter |
| -------- | ------- | ------- |
| 50       | 1       | 1       |
```

Comment: Unfortunately own goals can also have 'regular' in description so this is not going to differentiate them properly. The only reliable criteria is the value 'ownGoal' being present or not in description column.

Comment: I removed 'regular' from description column since it caused confusion. Regular goals are all goals that do not contain 'ownGoal' value in their description. There is no other way to tell them apart from own goals.